# Conditions for Kernel coercivity on a bilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form, coercive

Let $H = L^2([0,1])$, $K \in L^{\infty}([0,1]^2)$. I have the following bilinear form:
$$ a(u,v)=\int_{[0,1]^2}{K(x,y) u(x) v(y) dx dy} \;\;\; \forall u,v \in H $$
What conditions do I have to set for $ K $ so that $ a $ is coercive (i.e. $ \exists \, a_0 > 0 \; s.t. \; a(u,u) \ge a_0 \|u\|_H^2 $)? I'm suspecting both $ K $ symmetric and positive definite, but I am still not sure of how to formally prove it.

Comment: Can you show what you have done to solve this question?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is pretty much as far as I've gotten. The original question involves unique existence of $ u $ for $ a(u,v)=Lv $, where $ L $ is any element of $ H^* $, which I've been trying to solve using Lax-Milgram. I'm only missing coercivity for the bilinear form, and the conditions for $ K $ I put in the question are just intuitive conjectures based on experience, which are not enough to actually prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bilinear form $ a $ is coercive as long as we make the following assumptions regarding the Kernel function $ K $:

- $ K(x,x) \in C([0,1]) $ ;
- $ \inf_{x \in [0,1]} K(x,x) = a_0 > 0 $ ;
- $ K(x,y) = 0 \;\;\; \forall \; x \ne y $ .

Using these three conditions, $ \forall u \in H $ we get

$$ \begin{aligned} a(u,u) & = \int_{[0,1]^2} K(x,y) \: u(x) \: u(y) \: dx \, dy \\ & = \int_{0}^{1} K(x,x) \: u(x)^2 \: dx \\ & \ge a_0 \int_{0}^{1} u(x)^2 dx = a_0 \| u \|_{H}^{2} \end{aligned} $$

And thus, we get coercivity.

Comment: I don't think it is a valid answer: your choice of $K$ is null almost everywhere on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, thus the integral ends up being $0$. To achieve what you want we should have $K(x,y)=a_0\delta_x(y)$ which is not in $L^\infty$

Comment: I have restarted this discussion in another topic, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219692/coercivity-of-a-bilinear-form-on-l2 and it seems that your solution does not work

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer, but since I'm not a matematician I would be glad to have some feedback on the correctness of this answer.

I think your bilinear form is never coercive. Indeed, we can rewrite $a(u,u)$ as

$$\int_0^1 u(x)Tu(x)\ dx \qquad Tu(x):=\int_0^1 K(x,y)u(y)\ dy$$

Then, since $K$ is bounded, $T$ is an Hilber-Shmidt operator on $H$, so is compact in particular.
Thus, by the properties of compact operators,
$$\forall \delta>0\ \exists u\in H:\qquad  \|Tu\|_H\le \delta\|u\|_H$$

so that, taking this $u$, we get

$a(u,u)=\int_0^1 u(x)Tu(x)\ dx\le \|u\|_H\|Tu\|_H\le \delta \|u\|_H^2$

since this holds for every $\delta>0$, the bilinear form cannot be coercive.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long for me to validate your answer. I was waiting for the professor to share the exam's review, since the way he stated the question made it seem like coercivity was achievable; and indeed, it was.